# DataGrid showing square characters

Tags: c#, character-encoding, datatable

I've been looking around for solutions to this problem for a few days now, I haven't found any solution yet. I am building a toy audio player in C# and I have a small Access database of all the music files on my computer. When I import this database into a DataTable and then into a `DataGridView`, I get square characters like this (Can't post images here so here's a link):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCC2e.jpg

These characters do not exist in the database, as far as I can tell. I have been told to try the `ToString().Trim()` method, but I do not know how since I am using SQL to build the DataTable.

Here is the code:

```
public static DataTable GetLibraryDataTable()
    {
        OleDbConnection cnx = bTunesDB.GetConnection();
        cnx.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Artist, Title, Album, ReleaseYear, Genre, PlayCount, TrackOrderInAlbum, AlbumOrderInArtist, FilePath FROM Tracks ORDER BY Artist, AlbumOrderInArtist, TrackOrderInAlbum", cnx);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

And then to fill the datagridview:

```
LibraryDataView.DataSource = bTunesDB.GetLibraryDataTable();
```

I have tried using this code to trim the DataTable values but the problem persists:

```
var dataRows = dt.AsEnumerable();
foreach (var row in dataRows)
{
      var cellList = row.ItemArray.ToList();
      row.ItemArray = cellList.Select(x => x.ToString().Trim(null)).ToArray();
}
```

Would anyone have any ideas why this is happening? I'm hoping it's some kind of charset setting or something, but I'm not very familiar with `DataTables` and `DataGridView`.

Comment: It definitely appears to be caused by a fixed-size character string in the database.  Are you certain that the "squares" are `nulls`s?  Can you analyze one of the character strings in your debugger and determine whether all of the squares are the same value, and if so, identify what it is?  If these values are not null, you will need to change the value passed to `Trim()`.  You might also try `Trim('\0')`

Comment: @BrettWolfington: How should I try to see the character string? When I do Console.WriteLine it doesn't show the characters and when I select the output it stops at the real text, as if there was nothing else there. Same thing if I try to show it in a messagebox.

Comment: @BrettWolfington: Your solution of using Trim('\0') instead of null worked! Thank you. Could I trouble you to ask what's going on here and if there are any best practices to avoid this type of thing?